# Graft changes from one branch to another

Tags: git

I created a branch `a` off of master, then `b` off of `a` which I later merged back into `a`

```
a
|\
| b
| b
| / 
a
m
m
```

I am not ready to merge `a` into `master`, but would like to merge `b` (without any changes from `a`). What is the best way of doing that? Ideally after the operation I would have a tree like this

```
a
a
|\
| b
| b
| / 
m
m
```

With Hg I would just graft changes, but I have been told that is frowned upon with git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replay b on top of master, going from:

```
       a--A--...----B--a--a
      /    \       /
     /      b--b--b  (b branch)
    /             
m--m--m--m
```

to, with `git rebase --onto master A b`:

```
       a--A--...----B--a--a
      /    \       /
     /      b--b--b 
    /             
m--m--m--m--b'--b'--b' (b branch)
```

(`A` is the commit from which you created the `b` branch)

The only issue will be merging `a` later on back to `master`: I would do an interactive rebase if `a` on top of `B'` (which is "`master`+`b branch`"), and drop `B` (the first merge commit if `b` in a), in order to replay `a` on top of (`master`+`b`). Then the merge of `a` in `master` will be trivial.

Comment: The issue with doing that is that a couple of those `a` commits then make it into `master` I'm not ready for *any* of the `a` work to be merged

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Right, I missed that part. I have edited the answer accordingly.